# Extension attributes to add product attribute to the order summary on checkout?

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

I am trying to display a custom product attribute under the order summary list of items on checkout. I think it is fed by the `TotalsItemExtensionInterface`. I have the following trying to add the custom attribute to the collection exposed on the front end.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemExtensionInterface">
    <attribute code="product" type="string">
        <join reference_table="catalog_product" reference_field="product_id" join_on_field="entity_id">
            <field>custom_attribute</field>
        </join>
    </attribute>
</extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Any ideas on how this is done to attach a product attribute to a quote item in Magento 2?

**EDIT:** Attached is the screenshot of where I would like to get the attribute to show:
[image]

Also I am taking a different route, but have the same problem. I brought the attribute to the quote item through a migration so is now part of the `quote_item` table. But not part of the collection coming through. Any idea on how I get that attribute as part of the `quoteItem` object?

Comment: You can take a screenshot and show where you want show the custom product attribute?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Uploaded image and also an update. Still having this issue.

Comment: How about your current issue?

Comment: Try this fix: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3640 But in your case, having a join with catalog_product entity looks like too much.

Answer (score 12):

**1) The flow of cart summary in checkout page**

We can get the `totalsData` from:

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/quote.js**

```
var totalsData = window.checkoutConfig.totalsData;

return {
    totals: totals,
    ......
}
```

If we try to format the Json from `window.checkoutConfig`, we can see the `totalsData`. And, we can get the items from it.

[image]

Now, at look the checkout xml layout:

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/cart-items</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="thumbnail" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before_details</item>
                </item>
                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/subtotal</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after_details</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>

    </item>
</item>
```

In the front page:

[image]

**2) Add custom attribute**

Where is the `totalsData` from the PHP side?

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php**

```
public function getConfig()
{ 
    ......
    $output['postCodes'] = $this->postCodesConfig->getPostCodes();
    $output['imageData'] = $this->imageProvider->getImages($quoteId);
    $output['totalsData'] = $this->getTotalsData();
    ......
}
```

<del>So, we need to override this method, I think we should use Plugin to override this method.</del>

**Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="add_custom_product_attribute" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout\ConfigProviderPlugin" />
</type>
```

**Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout\ConfigProviderPlugin.php**

```
public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
{
    $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];
    foreach($items as $item) {
        //Your code here
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And then, we need to create your own js and html template files or override the exist files.

[EDIT]

We should try with:

> The proper way is to use `TotalsItemExtensionInterface` and add all
>   these via it

Create extension attributes:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemExtensionInterface">
        <attribute code="reward_points" type="int" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\ItemConverter">
        <plugin name="show-points-item" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Cart\Totals\ItemConverterPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Cart/Totals/ItemConverterPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Cart\Totals;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\ItemConverter;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemExtensionFactory;

class ItemConverterPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var TotalsItemExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $totalsItemExtensionFactory;

    /**
     * ItemConverterPlugin constructor.
     *
     * @param TotalsItemExtensionFactory $totalsItemExtensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        TotalsItemExtensionFactory $totalsItemExtensionFactory
    ) {
        $this->totalsItemExtensionFactory = $totalsItemExtensionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param ItemConverter $subject
     *
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterModelToDataObject(
        ItemConverter $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $extensionAttributes = $result->getExtensionAttributes();
        if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
            $extensionAttributes = $this->totalsItemExtensionFactory->create();
        }
        $pointsDelta = 24;
        $extensionAttributes->setRewardPoints($pointsDelta);
        $result->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

On the checkout page, we can check on Browser console:
`window.checkoutConfig.totalsData.items`

[image]

Comment: How could one add the specific product url to the item-array? This would clarify your already great question even more!

Comment: Hello Khoa, as per your answer i have added short description into window.checkoutConfig.totalsdata and window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData as well. when we reach checkout page the short description is coming, but when we move to payment or come back to shipping tab it dissapears. any idea ?

Comment: it will work until totals are recalculated on shipping method change etc. The proper way is to use TotalsItemExtensionInterface and add all these via it

Comment: @c0rewell I see, I need to test more.

Comment: @Sunil Verma Can you please help me? I need to get the product attribute.

Comment: I have just updated my answer with using extension attributes.

Comment: good explaination :

Comment: why is it not auto populated from quote_item custom attribute?

Comment: I tried to use your example and get an error
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\TotalsItemExtension::setRewardPoints()

Magento CLI version 2.2.7

Comment: @NikolaiSilin I had same error and solved it by using `$extensionAttributes->setData('reward_points', $pointsDelta);` instead.