# Magento 2 checkout page where is coming from a order summary section's data in payment step?

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1, onestepcheckout

Checkout page it displays order summary section.It has Product data displaying .Product infromation coming from `Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider.php` and from `getTotalsData()` function if it is in shipping step and when I switch in payment step order summary section display product information but it is not coming from `getTotals()` in payment section.

If I change code from `$output['totalsData'] = $this->getTotalsData()` to `$output['totalsData'] = array()` in `getConfig()` function so result is order summary product section not display in checkout `shipping step` but it displays in `payment step`

I have added following code in file: `pub\static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US\Magento_Checkout\template\summary\item`

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($parent, null, 2)"></pre>
```

And display following result in checkout page:-
I have changed code in `getTotalsData()` function in `Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider.php` path and add isbn attribute in totalsdata object but not diplay in payment step but it display in shipping step

Shipping Step 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFV0t.jpg
This above shipping step screenshot where it display totals information and also display my custom product attribute 'isbn'.

Payment Step 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlIe7.jpg
This above shipping step screenshot where it display totals information and not display my custom product attribute 'isbn'.

I have changed in core file `DefaultconfigProvider.php` temporary to check

And changed only this `getTotalsData()` function

```
private function getTotalsData()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface $totals */
        $totals = $this->cartTotalRepository->get($this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId());
        $items = [];
        /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\Item $item */
        foreach ($totals->getItems() as $item) {
            $data = $item->__toArray(); // custom code
            $data['isbn'] = 'ISBN-12345'; // custom code
            $items[] = $data;
        }
        $totalSegmentsData = [];
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\TotalSegment $totalSegment */
        foreach ($totals->getTotalSegments() as $totalSegment) {
            $totalSegmentArray = $totalSegment->toArray();
            if (is_object($totalSegment->getExtensionAttributes())) {
                $totalSegmentArray['extension_attributes'] = $totalSegment->getExtensionAttributes()->__toArray();
            }
            $totalSegmentsData[] = $totalSegmentArray;
        }
        $totals->setItems($items);
        $totals->setTotalSegments($totalSegmentsData);
        $totalsArray = $totals->toArray();
        if (is_object($totals->getExtensionAttributes())) {
            $totalsArray['extension_attributes'] = $totals->getExtensionAttributes()->__toArray();
        }
        return $totalsArray;
    }
```

And this is my details.html file which I have modified

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before_details') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<div class="product-item-details">

    <div class="product-item-inner">
        <div class="product-item-name-block">
            <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
            <div class="details-qty">
                <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Qty' --><!-- /ko --></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.qty"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="details-isbn">
                <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Isbn' --><!-- /ko --></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.isbn"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('after_details') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>

    <!-- ko if: (JSON.parse($parent.options).length > 0)-->
    <div class="product options" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active'}}">
        <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'View Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <div data-role="content" class="content">
            <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
            <dl class="item-options">
                <!--ko foreach: JSON.parse($parent.options)-->
                <dt class="label" data-bind="text: label"></dt>
                    <!-- ko if: ($data.full_view)-->
                    <dd class="values" data-bind="html: full_view"></dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko ifnot: ($data.full_view)-->
                    <dd class="values" data-bind="html: value"></dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

In payment step,product information where is coming from ?

Comment: please add screenshot to get clear idea of your issue.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: please share your defaultconfigprovider.php file code

Comment: Have you done with plugin method?

Comment: @Rakesh I have uninstall magento 2.1 and reinstallling magento  then step all thing then let you know and thanks for interest .I will let you know after all setup

Comment: @Rakesh I have added two code file which I have changed one is Defaultconfigprovider.php and details.html

Comment: you can test with below code

Comment: @Rakesh ok I will check your code.And advance thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can set your custom attribute inside checkout page summary block using below way,**

**app/code/{Package}/{Module}/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <!-- Set Custom attribute in chekcout page summary block -->
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="default_config_provider" type="Package\Module\Model\DefaultConfigProvider"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**`app/code/{Package}/{Module}/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php file`**

```
<?php
namespace Package\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface as QuoteItemRepository;

class DefaultConfigProvider
{
    private $checkoutSession;
    private $quoteItemRepository;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        QuoteItemRepository $quoteItemRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->quoteItemRepository = $quoteItemRepository;
    }

    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, $result)
    {        
        $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();
        if ($quoteId) {            
            $itemOptionCount = count($result['totalsData']['items']);
            $quoteItems = $this->quoteItemRepository->getList($quoteId);

            $isbnOptions = array();
            foreach ($quoteItems as $index => $quoteItem) {
                $quoteItemId = $quoteItem['item_id'];
                $isbnOptions[$quoteItemId] = $quoteItem['isbn'];               
            }

            for($i=0;$i<$itemOptionCount;$i++){
                $quoteParentId = $result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['item_id'];                    
                $currentOption = array();
                $currentOption = json_decode($result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['options'],true);

                $newOption = $isbnOptions[$quoteParentId];

                //for set new option inside current option tab
                if(count($newOption) > 0 && is_array($newOption)){                        
                    foreach($newOption as $key=>$value){
                        if( !is_array($value) ){
                            $currentOption[] = array('value'=>$value,'label'=>$key);
                        }
                    }
                    $result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['options'] = json_encode($currentOption);
                }                    
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with Plugin but did not work in old instance but I will check by this way

Comment: I have done successfully with above code.

Comment: Oh nice.I am excited I will sure check your code.thanks

Comment: isbn is product attribute so Should I add isbn column in sales_quote_item table ?

Comment: Yes first you have to add attribute to sales_quote_item table

Comment: ok I will check for that

Comment: not display isbn number in order summray section

Comment: Have you debug above code?

Comment: I have debug code by window.checkoutConfig and isbn number display in quoteItemData but not display in at frontend and other thing is  order summray product section comes from totalsdata object so quoteitemdata not display in order summray section

Comment: isbn number display in console debug nut not display at frontend becuase order summary section get product information from totals data object

Comment: You have to just remove browser cache, remove var folder and update product qty each time for development and your result is display

Comment: I lready remove var folder,and update qty and also add isbn column quote_item but not display in order summray only display product name,image and qty

Comment: product data display comes from totalsData object

Comment: you have to got inside $parent.options foreach in your html file because we set key as option in our code and you can look at above foreach. so check in those code

Comment: which html file ?

Comment: you have define above your question.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: I checked in details.html file using this code <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($parent, null, 2)"></pre> but it dsiplay  blanks in options array and it refers totalsdata object

Comment: You added code in totalsdata object option array but option display blank in debuging code

Comment: I have changed some code in your code in my file  this is code which I have changed  Now works on shipping page but not works on payment .if(count($isbnOptions) > 0 && is_array($isbnOptions)){                        
                    foreach($isbnOptions as $key=>$value){
                        if( !is_array($value) ){
                            $currentOption[] = array('value'=>$value,'label'=>$key);
                        }
                    }
     
                    $result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['options'] = json_encode($currentOption);
     
                }

Comment: I think we are close to solution but missing something.is it display options on your instance payment section ?

Comment: Yes in my system its display fine for both step. I have to add custom option for product level

Comment: Are you changing code ? Why do not display in my new instance ?

Comment: No i am telling that i have those type of requirements to dispaly custom option in summary block

Comment: Not sure whats the issue you have faced above code is working fine for me. May be you have little bit issue now

Comment: You have implemented in local machine using xampp ?

Comment: yes first develop task in local machine using ubuntu

Comment: I have implement fresh instance in local magento 2.1 community and in  server magento 2.1  enterprise edition but same issue face...

Comment: You have to keep above code and get value using $parent.option in html file

Comment: i  have updated code and remove json_encode from above code and keep $currentOption as plain value. now you can get value using $parent.option

Comment: ok let me try code

Comment: it throw error $prarent.option length error in console if I remove json_encode code And I implemented last week on linux server code in magento 2.1 enterprise edition  but it displayed only shipping step..I really headache for me this issue.you great developer  help for me thank you very much and still not display on payment page and plz added code with json_encode anyways I accept answer.thanks for your time

Comment: still not work yet?

Comment: no If I remove json_encode code it throw error in console about $parent.option.length and If put json_encode code ,it is displaying in shipping step but not display in payment step

Comment: Hello @RakeshJesadiya , I am also using the same plugin to customize the checkout sidebar. I have an issue, when checkout page load it working fine but when I click on next button and go to the payment section changes which I have made automaticully removed. 

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Product information is in `$output['totalsData']`

*vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php*

```
public function getConfig()
{ 
    ......

    $output['totalsData'] = $this->getTotalsData();
    ......
}
```

[image]

You should read more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/133732/33057

Comment: I have done same thing but it woks in shipping step but not working in payment step

Comment: If I put die function in gettotalsdata function so die function called in shipping step but not work in payment step

Comment: In the payment step, what you want to do?

Comment: I want to add product attribute called 'isbn' 'isbn' number display works perfectly in shipping step but not display in payment step

Comment: I have added product  'isbn' attribute value in totals items array it works fine shipping but payment step not display in payment step

Comment: After choose the next step - go to payment step- your isbn attribute lost?

Comment: Yes exactly 'isbn' attribute lost in payment step..

Comment: You can add more code lines. Because I don't know what you are trying to do. I will take a look your module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49920/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-test).

Comment: You can join the chat?

Comment: Yes in 2 min i am coming

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Alexglvr did you read this one: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/133732/33057