# How do I get all checkout data in a last custom step M2?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I created a custom step checkout after payment step.

This new step calls "Resume Order".

In that step, I need to show the selected shipping address, selected payment method.

I know that checkout is built with js, so how can I get all the previous selected items from shipping, payment and cart?

The step is already created like [magento documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html)

So, how to bring previous selected data from previous checkout steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the sidebar code. It's a good example.

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary**

Example:

1) Get Payment from quote `Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote`: `quote.paymentMethod()`. See here: **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/select-payment-method.j**s

2) Shipping Address and Billing Address: `quote.billingAddress()` and `quote.shippingAddress()`.

3) Quote items data: `quote.totals().items`

Can read more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/133732/33057