# How can you get the config value in html

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, html

I want to know if you can get the config value to html
I have a class which provides the value for config
Not sure how to get this checked in HTML

I have been looking at configproviderinterface

Comment: you can only do it using ko js

Comment: Is there any example I could take a look at, I have tried few but still no luck

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258408/magento-2-3-how-to-pass-custom-input-field-data-to-the-sidebar-summary

Comment: Thanks for that magefms, but I am not sure how that would pick up the config value from the admin. I have yes or no option in config if the value is yes I want to show in html if it’s not then show nothing. I have a class which checks the config not sure how that would get to html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override DefaultItem customer data `Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem`
And you can call the additional to KOJS This should allow you to grab the config value

```
protected function doGetItemData() {
//add new here 
e.g.
'check_enabled' => $this->Helper->getNewPrice(),
}
```

In you html

```
< !-- ko if: check_enabled ==1 -->
//do  h tag which does test
< !-- ko -->

< !-- ko ifnot: check_enabled ==1 -->
do  h tag which does testfailed
<!-- ko -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll give an example for **checkout** page, the idea is to load your config module in `phtml`, then you call that `phtml` in `html`

1. We create our **phtml**:

   > app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/templates/html/my-custom.phtml

   ```
   //you get your config module here then save it in $config 

    <?php echo $config; ?>
   ```
2. We instantiate our custom **phtml**:

   > app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml

   ```
   /* The Magento onepage code first, 
   then we add our myphtml var bellow the initial file code, 
   this file if you haven't it yet in your current theme, 
   you can copy it from :
   vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\onepage.phtml*/


   ...

   <?php $myphtml = $block->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/my-custom.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       var my_phtml = <?php echo json_encode($myphtml); ?>;
   </script>
   ```
3. We go to our **html** then bind our **phtml** content

   for exmple: we get our phtml in `shipping.html` file:

   > app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

   ```
   ...

   <div id="my-id" title="Information" data-bind="html:my_phtml"/> // here you get your config module value
   ```

I not tested it but it should work !

Comment: Hi Prince, I can’t use that I have tried it and that’s for checkout. I was doing it for minicart but I really appreciate it