# magento 2 how to add bootstrap classes in checkout_index_index.xml?

Tags: magento2, checkout

How to use bootstrap classes in checkout ?
Example -

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
here shipping information & payment information show
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
And here order summary will be show
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to add bootstapre css to this checkout page, right?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i already add bootstrap there,i need to divide sections

Comment: then you need to identify the html section of that particular element and then added that class to html entity like div or etc.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya ok try to do or there is any easy way ?

Comment: There is not any other way to apply class to specific element, so you need to do this only.

Comment: you have to override html template in order to do that

Comment: check this to get idea on how to override checkout html template https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258408/magento-2-3-how-to-pass-custom-input-field-data-to-the-sidebar-summary?answertab=active#tab-top